# Python Quart import error : cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'

Tags: python, quart

I am installing the Quart module for Python on a newly upgraded server - to Debian 11:

```
name -a
Linux 9D895EB 5.10.0-19-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.149-2 (2022-10-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I try running Quart I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/quart/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .app import Quart as Quart
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/quart/app.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .asgi import ASGIHTTPConnection, ASGILifespan, ASGIWebsocketConnection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/quart/asgi.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .debug import traceback_response
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/quart/debug.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Template
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .environment import Environment
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/defaults.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/filters.py", line 13, in <module>
    from markupsafe import soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)
```

When I installed quart on my previous dev box or laptop I didn't get this issue. I have seen comments about installing a previous version of a library, but, nothing related to quart as such.

Here is a list of installed module versions:

```
Jinja2             3.1.2
MarkupSafe         2.1.1
quart              0.18.3
requests           2.25.1
Werkzeug           2.2.2
```

Update:
With the update to MarkupSafe 2.1.1 and the others I now get:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/quart/cli.py", line 506, in _load_plugin_commands
for point in entry_points(group="quart.commands"):
TypeError: entry_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'
```

Comment: Are you sure about the MarkupSafe version? `soft_unicode` was removed in 2.1

Comment: @AndreySobolev Sorry, I was trying out the 'fix' of backing down the version.  Werzeug wants 2.1.0 + though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MarkupSafe` package is not 2.0.1

```
$ pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
$ pip list --no-index --format=json | jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="MarkupSafe").version'
2.0.1

>>> from markupsafe import soft_unicode
>>> 


$ pip install markupsafe==2.1.0
$ pip list --no-index --format=json | jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="MarkupSafe").version'
2.1.0

>>> from markupsafe import soft_unicode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/home/cetver/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)
```

## UPD:

Update https://github.com/python/importlib_metadata

or

Update Python to 3.10 https://github.com/pallets/quart/blob/0.18.3/src/quart/cli.py#L498

Comment: Updating importlib_metadata and markupsafe worked thank you.  If you add the importlib_metadata I will give it a tick.  Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The root cause with your question may stem from a dependency management conflict between two software ecosystems. According to the error message, your markupsafe was installed using pip at the path `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/markupsafe/`. The jinja2 that depends on it was installed using apt at the path `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2`. The versions of the two are not compatible. In fact, there is a version of markupsafe in the system that jinja2 correctly depends on, but the Python interpreter prioritizes the markupsafe installed by pip, leading to this issue. There are typically two solutions to this problem: (1) Use pip to uninstall markupsafe, and then reinstall it using apt, or uninstall jinja2 using apt and reinstall it using pip. (2) Use Python's imp module to customize the path and import the markupsafe from the apt path before importing jinja2. An example is as follows:

```
import imp
path = ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('markupsafe', path)
imp.load_module("markupsafe", fp, pathname, description)
```

Hope my diagnosis is helpful to you！